# xml transformation using xalan returns in-consistent results

Tags: xslt

We are encountering a strange issue in Production environment which we are not able to replicate in any environments. The Order Process & Management application which generates this error processes thousands of orders in a day avg. 4000 order. The order xmls are transformed using various xslt to update order data during each stage of the order lifecycle processe. 
However once a day, there will be an OrderUpdateException thrown by the underlying API of Order Service & Management application for an order when the output of xml transformation goes awry. Order fallout management built-in into the application enables the user to retry or re-submit the order task which failed in the first place. The task invokes a stateless session bean that modifies order data by applying transformation of the order xml using xalan. The retry always succeeds without user ever having to modify order data before submitting the task.

We know the reason why it failed in the first place but don't know what exactly triggered it to result in wrong transformation.

Order XML:

```
<GetOrder.Response xmlns="urn:com:metasolv:oms:xmlapi:1">
    <OrderID>243193</OrderID>   
    <_root>
    ....
        <Wireless>
            ...
            ....
            <MDN>
                <Action>NONE</Action>
                ....
                ...
                <Services>
                    <Voice>
                        <ServiceName>VOICE</ServiceName>
                        <ServiceStatus>Initial</ServiceStatus>
                        <FulfillmentItems>
                            <FulfillmentItem index="1353944898394">
                                <FulfillmentItemCode>DCF1</FulfillmentItemCode>                         
                                <FulfillmentMessages/>
                                <Attributes/>
                            </FulfillmentItem>
                            <FulfillmentItem index="1353944898409">
                                <FulfillmentItemCode>HCFB</FulfillmentItemCode>
                                <FulfillmentItemCodeDescription>FC-VOICE</FulfillmentItemCodeDescription>
                                <FulfillmentMessages/>
                                <Attributes/>
                            </FulfillmentItem>
                        </FulfillmentItems>
                    </Voice>
                </Services>
            </MDN>
        </Wireless>
    </_root>
</GetOrder.Response>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="oms:Wireless">
    <OrderDataUpdate xmlns="http://www.metasolv.com/OMS/OrderDataUpdate">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="oms:MDN"/>
    </OrderDataUpdate>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="oms:MDN">
    <xsl:call-template name="voice_template">
        <xsl:with-param name="mdnId" select="$mdnId"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="oldmdnId" select="$oldmdnId"/>
        ...
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:call-template>

<xsl:template name="voice_template"> 
    <xsl:param name="mdnId"/> 
    <xsl:param name="oldmdnId"/> 
    <xsl:param name="minId"/> 
    ....
    .....


    <xsl:for-each select="oms:Services/oms:Voice/oms:FulfillmentItems/oms:FulfillmentItem"> 
        <xsl:variable name="fulfillmentItem_index"> 
            <xsl:value-of select="@index"/> 
        </xsl:variable> 

        <Add path="/Wireless/MDN/Services/Voice/FulfillmentItems/FulfillmentItem[@index='{$fulfillmentItem_index}']/Attributes"> 

        ----
        ----
        </Add>
    <xsl:for-each>
<xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="* | @* | text()">
    <!-- do nothing -->
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

Transformed output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<OrderDataUpdate xmlns="http://www.metasolv.com/OMS/OrderDataUpdate" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
    <Add xmlns="" path="1353944898394']/Attributes"> 
        <Attribute> 
            <name>HLR-MSISDN</name> 
            <value>2045731730</value> 
        </Attribute> 
        <Attribute> 
            <name>HLR-IMSI</name> 
            <value>302660397124421</value> 
        </Attribute> 
        <Attribute> 
            <name>HLR-NON_MTS_IMSI</name> 
            <value>302370397124421</value> 
        </Attribute> 
    </Add> 
    <Add xmlns="" path="/Wireless/MDN/Services/Voice/FulfillmentItems/FulfillmentItem[@index='1353944898409']/Attributes"> 
    <Attribute> 
        <name>HLR-MSISDN</name> 
        <value>2045731730</value> 
    </Attribute> 
    ....
<OrderDataUpdate>
```

We discovered that wrong value was getting set for variable "fulfillmentItem_index" during the 1st iteration of the for-loop. For consecutive iterations, correct value was being set.
As a result of which, the application throws OrderUpdateException and stops processing the particular order. On re-submitting the same task however, the order process resume as if nothing really happened in the first place.

The application runs on Weblogic Application Server 9.2 MP3. We also ran a environment check and this is what it threw up:

.I ran a environment check and this is what it threw up.

```
<checkEnvironmentExtension> 
     <EnvironmentCheck version="$Revision: 1.29 $"> 
          <environment> 
               <item key="version.DOM.draftlevel">2.0fd</item> 
               <item key="java.class.path">:/home/weblogic/bea/patch_weblogic923/profiles/default/sys_manifest_classpath/weblogic_patch.jar:/opt/java1.5/lib/tools.jar:/home/weblogic/bea/weblogic92/server/lib/Bug8841241_920mp1.jar:/home/weblogic/bea/weblogic92/server/lib/weblogic_sp.jar:/home/weblogic/bea/weblogic92/server/lib/weblogic.jar:/home/weblogic/bea/weblogic92/server/lib/webservices.jar::/home/weblogic/bea/weblogic92/common/eval/pointbase/lib/pbclient51.jar:/home/weblogic/bea/weblogic92/server/lib/xqrl.jar:/home/weblogic/AQJMSHOME/AQJMS/StartupClass/lib/WLS9.0/AQJMSStartupClass.jar:/home/weblogic/AQJMSHOME/jar_files/aqapi13.jar:</item> 
               <item key="version.JAXP">1.1 or higher</item> 
               <item key="java.ext.dirs">/opt/java1.5/jre/lib/ext</item> 
               <item key="version.xerces2">Xerces-J 2.8.1</item> 
               <item key="version.xerces1">Xerces 1.4.4</item> 
               <item key="version.xalan2_2">Xalan Java 2.7.0</item> 
               <item key="version.xalan1">not-present</item> 
               <item key="version.ant">Apache Ant version 1.6.2 compiled on August 5 2004</item> 
               <item key="java.version">1.5.0.17</item> 
               <item key="version.DOM">2.0</item> 
               <item key="version.crimson">not-present</item> 
               <item key="sun.boot.class.path">/opt/java1.5/jre/lib/rt.jar:/opt/java1.5/jre/lib/i18n.jar:/opt/java1.5/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/opt/java1.5/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/opt/java1.5/jre/lib/jce.jar:/opt/java1.5/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/opt/java1.5/jre/classes</item> 
               <item key="version.SAX">2.0</item> 
               <item key="version.xalan2x">Xalan Java 2.7.0</item> 
          </environment> 
          <status result="OK"/> 
     </EnvironmentCheck> 
</checkEnvironmentExtension>
```

Appreciate if someone could help me explain this odd behaviour. We see this on a daily basis with at least 1 or 2 orders regularly failing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try replacing `<xsl:variable name="fulfillmentItem_index"> <xsl:value-of select="@index"/></xsl:variable>` with: `<xsl:variable name="fulfillmentItem_index" select="@index"> `

Comment: You say you tracked this issue down to the `fulfillmentItem_index` variable.  Does that mean you have an example of the bad XML?  What does it look like?  What do you mean when you say the "wrong value was being set"? In what way was it wrong?

Comment: I think I will give a twirl to suggestion given by @Dimitre. There is nothing wrong with order xml as well as the xslt applying transformation. I had raised a Service Request with Oracle who own this product sometime back but nothing good came out of it. The issue remains un-solved. Unfortunately we don't have control over the java code which does this transformation since the core API does it for us. We only develop the xsls and the define the order tasks(manual, automated etc.) and processes for the workflow. We map the xsls to each of the workflow tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Tough one. You certainly haven't supplied enough information for anyone here to come up with the answer. But I would check that you are using the Apache version of Xerces and not the Sun/Oracle JDK version. The latter is buggy, and in my experience the bug is often a corruption of an attribute value. The bug was raised years ago, and it's clear Oracle have no intention of fixing it.

Comment: Thanks for your time. The order process application certainly uses xalan 7.0 for transformation. You feel the xerces parser could be causing this problem? I see 2 versions of them                 <item key="version.xerces2">Xerces-J 2.8.1</item> 
<item key="version.xerces1">Xerces 1.4.4</item>

Comment: It's only a hunch, something to try. I don't see how your environment check can tell you which parser is actually being used, it will only tell you what's available for use.